# Cypher Neo4j - Query that uses the clause 'IN' on the collection is very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi i'm trying to import some data from CSV files in **Neo4j 2.3.1**. I've already imported some nodes of type **:Author** and **:Article**.

The **Author** node is composed of properties like:

1. *key* -> String
2. *principal_name* -> String
3. *alias* -> Collection of String
4. ........

**I've also added index on principal_name, alias and key.**

The problem comes when I try to import the relationships between nodes of type Article and Author.

The CSV has this type of structure:

```
articleKey,authorName
```

Has a naive solution i've tried to create the relationship using a query like this one:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myPath.csv" AS line
MATCH (art:Article{key: line.key1})
MATCH (auth:Author) WHERE line.key2 IN (auth.alias)
CREATE UNIQUE (auth)-[:AUTHOR_OF]->(art);
```

The query is painfully slow because the second MATCH is really slow as i discovered using the profiler. It takes **10-12 seconds** to create every relation because i've many Authors in the db(around 1000000).

So i'm looking for a way to execute a query like this one to get a faster execution(is an example to illustrate the structure that i want to obtain):

```
MATCH (auth:Author{principal_name: line.key2})
IF auth null THEN
  MATCH (auth:Author) WHERE line.key2 IN (auth.alias)
END
```

There is a way to do that with Cypher ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed your model so that all of an `Author` node's names (both the principal name and all the aliases) are all in separate `Name` nodes, like this:

```
(auth:Author)-[:HAS_NAME]->(name:Name {name: 'Fred McGillicutty'})
```

Then the query would be simply:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myPath.csv" AS line
MATCH
  (art:Article { key: line.key1 }),
  (auth:Author)-[:HAS_NAME]->(name:Name { name:line.key2 })
CREATE (auth)-[:AUTHOR_OF]->(art);
```

If you create indexes on `:Article(key)`, and `:Name(name)`, this query should be very efficient.

Comment: The proposed solution is the same that I had thought too for faster query execution. When I modeled data, naively I thought that adding an index on the collection would have solved the problem. Instead I see  from the profiler that the index on the collection  is not used to answer the query.

Answer (score 0):

If many authors have aliases and if you expect to query on these aliases you should model them as nodes. I think this will speed up queries for creating relationships and allows for more flexible queries involving aliases.

```
(:Alias)<-[:HAS]-(:Author)-[:AUTHOR_OF]->(:Article)
```

Add indexes on all nodes. If possible use [uniqueness constraints](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html#query-constraints-unique-nodes).

You can now query for `Alias` and `Author` nodes to add relationships:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myPath.csv" AS line
MATCH (art:Article {key: line.key1})
// get the Author directly or by alias
MATCH (alias:Alias)<-[:HAS]-(auth:Author)
WHERE alias.principal_name = line.key2 OR auth.principal_name = line.key2
CREATE (auth)-[:AUTHOR_OF]->(art)
```

With indexes the lookups should be pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the solution that you proposed is quite similar to the one proposed from @cybersam. I choose the other one only because is more general. At the end is the same idea that I'd had to sort it out. But I was wondering why the index on the collection was never used.